# Sort str strwords in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Can i make little short that code? I would not like to write this too many times, so I would like to make it shorter. just for the first 5, i don't want for all the lines of the textbox.

```
str2 = TxtBoxIntDraws1.Lines(0)
Dim strWords2 As String() = str2.Split(",")
str3 = TxtBoxIntDraws1.Lines(1)
Dim strWords3 As String() = str3.Split(",")
str4 = TxtBoxIntDraws1.Lines(2)
Dim strWords4 As String() = str4.Split(",")
str5 = TxtBoxIntDraws1.Lines(3)
Dim strWords5 As String() = str5.Split(",")
str6 = TxtBoxIntDraws1.Lines(4)
Dim strWords6 As String() = str6.Split(",")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like following

```
For idx = 0 To 4
    str = TxtBoxIntDraws1.Lines(idx)
    Dim strWords As String() = str.Split(",")
Next idx
```

If you want to process the split words later you can save the data to an array and process later. 
Follow the following code for this.

```
Dim idx As Integer
Dim strWords(5)() As String
For idx = 0 To 4
    str = TxtBoxIntDraws1.Lines(idx)
    strWords(idx) = str.Split(",")
Next idx

' process strWords
```

Comment: Good try but unfortunately you will overwrite strWords on each iteration and only end up with the last split of the 5th line.

Comment: @Mary, I have updated the answer. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrase of the answer by Vignesh Kumar A. This will give you lines 1 - 4. The index starts at zero.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim blankList As New List(Of String())
    For i = 0 To 3
        blankList.Add(TextBox1.Lines(i).Split(","c))
    Next
End Sub
```